# How to Populate this HTML Table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mysql File:

```
    <?php
  function query($sql, $array) {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "verifyUser";
    $password = "test";
    $dbname = "verify";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $stack = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($stack, $row);
            if(!$array) {
                return $row;
            }
        }
        return $stack;
    }
    $conn->close();

}
?>
```

My php file:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Serial</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

        include_once("mysql.php");
        $result = query("SELECT ProductId, Name, SerialId FROM product", true);
        while ($row = mysqli_query($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ProductId'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SerialId'] . "</td></tr>";
        }

    ?>
</table>
```

Output:

```
Id  Name    Serial
```

This is my first day trying to do anything with php. So go easy on me :)
I've been following different tutorials and looking at the php documentation, but I have not be able to get my table to print anything besides the table headers.
I don't think my query is wrong, because I return results in workbench
https://gyazo.com/ab588fa7b7498444a5e8dcd1b172f315

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, kudos for diving in and trying to learn a valuable new skill! I think you're def on the right track here, though as you admit, you're not quite there. I have one initial question, why do you have two separate files here? IMHO, I think they could easily be combined into one.

Comment: Another issue I see off hand is in your bottom php file, you are trying to use a sql query to populate a table, which won't work while ($row = mysqli_query($result)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ProductId'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SerialId'] . "</td></tr>";
        } I think you need to use the data in $stack here.

Comment: I used two separate files to try to re-use as much code as possible. That was my logic at least. 
What is the best way to get the $stack data?

Comment: See my answer below, it should at least get you in the right direction. Also, go do some research on the foreach() method in PHP, it iterates through an array. That should get you started. Play around with it some, and if you have any additional issues, let me know.

Comment: Also also, while you're still young and impressionable in this field, go do some research on PDO and SQL injections. The DB query method you are using (Mysqli) has actually been discovered to be pretty unsafe, PDO is the way to go today.

Comment: Also also also, get in the habit of not putting user/pass in your code :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $table='<table>
            <tr>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Serial</th>
           </tr>';


  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "verify";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

  $stack = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($stack, $row);
    if(!$array) {
        return $row;
     }
 }
}

$conn->close();

 $table_content='';
 foreach($stack as $item)
 {
  $table_content.= "<tr>
                     <td>" . $row['ProductId'] . "</td>
                     <td>" . $row['Name'] . " </td>.  
                     <td>" . $row['SerialId'] . "</td>
                   </tr>";

 }
echo $table.$table_content.'</table>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Serial</th>
</tr>

<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "verify";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$stack = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($stack, $row);
        if(!$array) {
            return $row;
        }
    }
}

$conn->close();




foreach($stack as $item)
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ProductId'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>.  <td>" . $row['SerialId'] . "</td></tr>";
}




?>
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the help so far. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same output I originally had.